# Set static page/post from another blog on same network

Tags: posts, multisite, redirect, actions

I have a multisite project and have a small problem with static front page/post. In general i am looking for a way to choose a static page/post out of the whole network on my main blog. Now i'm not sure however how this can be done.

As i see it there are three ways to do it:

1. Doing an old fashioned redirect to the page in question using header("Location: ");
2. Extending, create a settings option and action or finding a plugin which lets me choose a post from any blog on my network.
3. Overriding the build in function that chooses the front page and use the switch and restore blog functions to fetch the correct post-ID. If so with what function/tag should i use if that is possible to do it that way?

Which way would you recommend or is there another way to do this?

**Added**

The code i have (besides the settings-reading extension which workes fine) is as follows:

```
$get_blog = get_option("listah_static_blogid");
$get_pageid = get_option("listah_static_pageid");
switch_to_blog($get_blog);
// Somehow use the get_pageid to display the page in question and set as front_page for main blog
restore_current_blog();
```

Comment: Have you made any effort to implement any of these options?

Comment: @s_ha_dum yes i have. Created a small add-on to choose global posts and in a way overriding the build in static page chooser in Settings>Reading panel. But i'm not sure how to implement this on the site itself so it chooses the correct site from the correct blog and displays it as the front page on my main blog.

Comment: Ok. Post the code you are working on, please.

Comment: @s_ha_dum The code i have is basically the extension to the settings-reading page where is set the two options, fetch blogID, fetch postID. However the part i have a problem with i don't have a code because i'm not sure how to implement it. I'll edit my question to add the part i have. Don't know if that is the correct way to do this.

Comment: you want only the content or the look as well?

Comment: We decided to do use a basic header("location: "). So this problem is solved for now.